# Why a promise with a value undefined is returned from "findLocation()"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I print a pending promise in purpose**. As you see I call and print findLocation from the get request callback, but a promise is returned with a value undefined.
Tried to debug this, the returned value from findLocation is "locations[random]" which is an object. couldn't find the reason why it prints a promise with undefined. I want the promise's value to be "locations[random]" which is a valid object.

```
import express from "express";
import getCities from "./api/getCities.js";
import useOpenTripMap from "./api/useOpenTripMap.js";
 
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
// gets an array of cities
const citiesArray = getCities();
const radius = 1000;
// locations results limit
const limit = 20;
 
const findLocation = async () => {
  return citiesArray
    .then((cities) => {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length);
      useOpenTripMap("geoname", encodeURI("name=" + cities[random].name)).then(
        (city) => {
          useOpenTripMap(
            "radius",
            encodeURI(
              `radius=${radius}&limit=${limit}&lon=${city.lon}&lat=${city.lat}&format=json`
            )
          ).then((locations) => {
            // if no location found try again with another city
            if (!Array.isArray(locations) || !locations.length) {
              return findLocation();
            }
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * locations.length);
            // console.log(locations[random]);
            return locations[random]; //returns an object
          });
        }
      );
    })
    .catch((error) => error);
};
 
app.get("/random", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(findLocation()); //a pending promise with undefined value
  // .then((location) => {
  //   console.log(location);
  //   res.json(location);
  // })
  // .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
 
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server is running on port", port);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to await the promise. So sticking with the then/catch version (even though I recommend using async/await).

```js
findLocation().then(value => console.log(value));
```

or async/await syntax

```js
app.get("/random", async (req, res, next) => {
  const location = await findLocation();
  console.log(location);
});
```

And you probably want to return any `useOpenTripMap`

Update: Try this implementation of findLocation

```js
const findLocation = async () => {
  try {
    const cities = await citiesArray; // a promise?!
    // better would be
    const cities = await getCities();
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length);
    const city = await useOpenTripMap(
      "geoname",
      encodeURI("name=" + cities[random].name)
    );
    const locations = await useOpenTripMap(
      "radius",
      encodeURI(
        `radius=${radius}&limit=${limit}&lon=${city.lon}&lat=${city.lat}&format=json`
      )
    );
    if (!Array.isArray(locations) || !locations.length) {
      return findLocation(); // recursive call with no parameter change?
    }
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * locations.length);
    // console.log(locations[random]);
    return locations[random]; //returns an object
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I know this, but "location" is undefined. I want the promise's value to be "locations[random]" but it's undefined. I print a pending promise in purpose.

Comment: Hi @morh I added an async/await implementation for findLocation, btw. I just assumed that citiesArray is a promise? not a function but a pending promise?

Comment: Yes citiesArray is a promise and your implementation of "findLocation" returns the expected value :). I want to understand why mine doesn't.

Comment: Like I said, you don't return the `useOpenTripMap.then`

Comment: anything you don't return will just resolve within the function, but won't actually ever be returned. So add a return for any value that you add `.then` :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `return`s in the `then`ables. That's why promise(`citiesArray`) returning `undefined`. To more readable and simplistic, use `async/await` approach.

```
const findLocation = async () => {
  return citiesArray
    .then((cities) => {
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length);
      // here return missed 
      return useOpenTripMap("geoname", encodeURI("name=" + cities[random].name)).then(
        (city) => {
          // here too 
          return useOpenTripMap(
            "radius",
            encodeURI(
              `radius=${radius}&limit=${limit}&lon=${city.lon}&lat=${city.lat}&format=json`
            )
          ).then((locations) => {
            // if no location found try again with another city
            if (!Array.isArray(locations) || !locations.length) {
              return findLocation();
            }
            random = Math.floor(Math.random() * locations.length);
            // console.log(locations[random]);
            return locations[random]; //returns an object
          });
        }
      );
    })
    .catch((error) => error);
};
```

**async/await approach**

```
const findLocation = async () => {
  try {
    const cities = await citiesArray()
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * cities.length);
    const city = await useOpenTripMap("geoname", encodeURI("name=" + cities[random].name))
    const locations = await useOpenTripMap(
      "radius",
      encodeURI(
        `radius=${radius}&limit=${limit}&lon=${city.lon}&lat=${city.lat}&format=json`
      )
    )
    // if no location found try again with another city
    if (!Array.isArray(locations) || !locations.length) {
      return findLocation();
    }
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * locations.length);
    // console.log(locations[random]);
    return locations[random]; //returns an object

  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
};
```